# Sorting and Indexing Rank as Bigint or Float

Tags: mysql, sorting, floating-point, sql-order-by

Using MySql. I have a table of users and need to store user's rank in one of the columns. The application determines the rank and it happens to be a signed float. Example of ranks would be:

```
7732.5366604
7733.0252967
7740.8813879
-7736.5642667
-42.0223467
81121.3647382
```

So basically I always have at least seven places after "." and number is signed.

I need to create index on this field and ORDER BY it.

From what I understand, I have 2 choices:

1. Store the number as is in the most appropriate mysql type (float?)
2. format the value to remove the dot (in application layer) and store it as a signed bigint so that -7736.5642667 would become -77365642667. If for some reason I did not have 7 places after dot, I would append zeros, so that: 234.34565 would become 234.3456500 and then become 2343456500

I'm wondering which of the two would be faster in terms of storing, indexing and sorting.

Thanks and appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the algorithm behind index in terms of difference between indexing int and float but I would do a benchmark on big data set. If no difference in performance, then I would use float because that's your numbers and you don't have to do any formatting.